# Can the Linux OS be fully learned through the exclusive use of Khali?

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I know the basics of Linux but not the detailed ins & outs of it, **can the Linux OS be fully learned through the exclusive use of Khali??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and no.

I think it's safe to say that you can learn Linux whilst using Kali, since Kali is Linux. But I also think it's not a bad idea to learn Linux before delving into the security side of Kali, for a few reasons.

First of all, it'll make your life easier. If you know how to use Linux, then using the tools that Kali ships with will be a lot easier.

Secondly, understanding Linux usually also means that you are gaining an understanding of some basic operating system theory. Sure, all the OS's out there are different, but if you can look at one and really analyze it, then you'll better understand the theory behind how an OS works. Since Linux is open source and lets you dig around in every nook and cranny, it's a great one to study, and it will add to your knowledge of the fundamentals.

Thirdly, understanding those fundamentals, of course, is an important step toward seeing how they fail (which is how they get compromised).

Finally, learning Linux will also give you a better understanding that Kali is just one flavour of Linux pre-loaded with a bunch of security-focused tools. Eventually, you might find that some other flavour of Linux suits you better, but you will not feel bound to Kali because you will understand how to get those tools elsewhere.

So yes, learn Linux. But feel free to learn it on Kali. Learn both security and Linux concurrently, but make sure you don't slack off. Learn both earnestly.

Answer (score 1):

I've always felt that I learn best by having an application in mind and amplified further by having a solid interest in the subject. Whether it be learning gimp or kismet, give it a go and at some point you will have learned the same basic functionality of your distribution.